# Como buscar uma variável de outra função no IF da função?

Tags: python, variáveis, undefined

Bom dia,

Este programa que estou praticando, já possui outras respostas, no entanto resolvi incrementar de outra forma. O programa pede para solicitar o valor da hora de trabalho e a quantidade trabalhada no mês, a partir daí realizar os cálculos e imprimir os resultados. Depois de muito apanhar, o programa parou de dar erro e chegou a imprimir parte do extrato (apenas das variáveis global) e logo após apresentou erro de variável não definida, conforme abaixo:

---

```
Informe o nome completo do funcionário: José das Quantas
Informe o valor do salário por hora: 45
Informe as horas trabalhadas no mês: 34
  
###################################################################################
                              EXTRATO BASE DE SALÁRIO
###################################################################################
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Funcionário: José das Quantas
                     Salário Bruto: (45.0 * 34.0)        : R$ 1530.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Formação Acadêmica/Tecnologia/Udemy/Python/estruturaDeDecisao.py", line 61, in <module>
NameError: name 'impostoIR' is not defined
```

---

Todo o código descrito é esse e os erros estão na função IMPRIMIR:

```
nome = str(input('Informe o nome completo do funcionário:'))
valorHora = float(input(' Informe o valor do salário por hora: '))
horasTrabalhadas = float(input('Informe as horas trabalhadas no mês: '))
salarioBruto = (valorHora * horasTrabalhadas)

def calculoDescontos(salarioBruto):
    descontoIR = 0
    inss = salarioBruto * 0.10
    fgts = salarioBruto * 0.11
    sindicato = salarioBruto * 0.03
    impostoIR = 0
    if salarioBruto <= 900:
        descontoIR = 'Isento'
        totalDesconto = sindicato + inss
        salarioLiquido = salarioBruto - totalDesconto
    elif salarioBruto > 900 and salarioBruto <= 1500:
        impostoIR = 5
        descontoIR = salarioBruto * 0.05
        totalDesconto = sindicato + inss + descontoIR
        salarioLiquido = salarioBruto - totalDesconto
    elif salarioBruto > 1500 and salarioBruto <= 2500:
        impostoIR = 10
        descontoIR = salarioBruto * 0.1
        totalDesconto = sindicato + inss + descontoIR
        salarioLiquido = salarioBruto - totalDesconto
    else:
        impostoIR = 20        
        descontoIR = salarioBruto * 0.2
        totalDesconto = sindicato + inss + descontoIR
        salarioLiquido = salarioBruto - totalDesconto

    imprimir(salarioBruto, sindicato, descontoIR, totalDesconto, fgts, salarioLiquido, impostoIR, inss)

def imprimir(salarioBruto, sindicato, descontoIR, totalDesconto, fgts, salarioLiquido, impostoIR, inss):
    print('  ')
    print('###################################################################################')
    print('                              EXTRATO BASE DE SALÁRIO                              ')
    print('###################################################################################')
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Funcionário: {} '.format(nome))
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('                     Salário Bruto: ({} * {})        : R$ {} '.format(valorHora, horasTrabalhadas, salarioBruto))
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('    (-) IR ({}%)                    : R$  {} '.format(impostoIR, descontoIR))
    print('    (-) INSS ( 10%)                 : R$  {} '.format(inss))
    print('    (-) SINDICATO ( 3%)             : R$  {} '.format(sindicato))
    print('    FGTS (11%)                      : R$  {} '.format(fgts))
    print('    Total de descontos              : R$  {} '.format(totalDesconto))
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('                                     Salário Liquido                 : R$  {}  '.format(salarioLiquido))
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('  ')
```

É a primeira vez que posto nesse site, então se tiver algo faltando ou desconfigurado me avisem para consertar.

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: A definição da função imprimir requer 8 parâmetros, mas quando vc chama ela vc colocou só 7.

Comment: Estava faltando mesmo, mas não adiantou. Apenas solicita e lê os 3 input´s.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No seu caso, como vc mesmo encontrou a solução, basta [marcar a sua resposta abaixo como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado! Após o prazo estipulado irei marcar como resolvido então. Vlw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando um outro código, verifiquei que faltou chamar a função após o último print:

calculoDescontos(salarioBruto)

Agora o programa rodou e com a formatação devida. Obrigado **Aviana** pelo toque da falta do parâmetro.

Agradeço!